# How to catch and fix a warning/error that goes away almost immediately?

Tags: warning-messages

I wrote the following code

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

simulateRandomWalk[steps_Integer, prob_] :=
  Module[{accumulatedSteps, plotRange},

   accumulatedSteps = 
    Prepend[Accumulate[
      RandomChoice[{N[1 - prob], N[prob]} -> {-1, 1}, steps]], 0];
   plotRange = {{0, steps}, {Min[accumulatedSteps] - 1, 
      Max[accumulatedSteps] + 1}};

   Animate[
    ListLinePlot[{Range[0, n], Take[accumulatedSteps, n + 1]} // 
      Transpose,
     PlotRange -> plotRange], {n, Range[0, steps], 
     AnimationRepetitions -> 1}
    ]
   ];

simulateRandomWalk[100, 0.5]
```

to simulate a random walk with $n$ steps and a probability $p$ of going up (and $1 - p$ for going down). However, it appears that `ListLinePlot` gives me some warnings/error that go away almost immediately, so I cannot see them well, let alone deal with them. Any ideas as to what I should do?

Comment: Just a guess: replace `Module` with `DynamicModule`.  This doesn't answer *how* to diagnose errors, it's simply a suggestion based on experience.  :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Thanks; the lack of `DynamicModule` is indeed what was causing the problems!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting!  Add `Pause[10]` between your two lines, and you'll get some time to peruse the output.  Equivalently, split it into two cells, and re-run the definition of `simulateRandomWalk` *after* you've got some valid output.

The output of `Animate` is "Dynamic".  When a new definition of the module inside `simulateRandomWalk` is created, a new local variable called `accumulatedSteps$5432` (or similar) is created, so the previous output from `simulateRandomWalk` is invalidated because the previous `accumulatedSteps$4321` (or whatever the local variable happens to be called) gets deleted.  The output of `Animate` then attempts to re-render but it has insufficient input so you get your error message.  However, valid output gets re-created a few milliseconds later because the function `simulateRandomWalk` gets called next.

If you use `DynamicModule` instead of `Module` the issue goes away.  I don't understand dynamic outputs well enough to explain the mechanics exactly.

Comment: `DynamicModule` is indeed what I needed! Thanks a lot for the clear explanation; I'll do some research on the subject myself (seeing as I'm relatively inexperienced with Mathematica).

Answer (score 1):

If you use `With` instead and factor in `plotRange` directly, it also works flawlessly:

```
simulateRandomWalk[steps_Integer, prob_] := 
  With[{accumulatedSteps = 
    Prepend[Accumulate[
      RandomChoice[{N[1 - prob], N[prob]} -> {-1, 1}, steps]], 0]},
  Animate[
    ListLinePlot[{Range[0, n], Take[accumulatedSteps, n + 1]}
      //Transpose, 
      PlotRange -> {{0, steps},
      {Min[accumulatedSteps] - 1, 
       Max[accumulatedSteps] + 1}}],
    {n, Range[0, steps]}, AnimationRepetitions -> 1]];
```